# Getting old school trees with forest

Tags: linguistics, forest

According to the manual of `forest`it was developed to get trees like the one on the right-hand side of the following figure rather then the one on the left-hand side:

[image]

Usually I want the dense trees too, but there is a situation in which the other trees are more appropriate. For Tree Adjoining Grammar, one wants to have a format that allows other phrases to be plugged into the leaf nodes. This does not work for the second tree in the figure below:

[image]

So, question: Is there a way to specify in the style statement for `tag` trees below that the upper NP nodes in the second example should be placed further to the left so that there is no other material below these two NPs?

```
\documentclass{minimal}   

\usepackage{forest}



\forestset{
tag/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top}},
% a style that creates an arrow pointing to the substitution node from a tree top node encoded as daughter 
substitution/.style={edge={<-,dashed},l+=\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$\downarrow$,
          [NP, substitution
            [John]]]
        [VP
                [V
                        [laughs]]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{2em}
\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$_2^2\downarrow$]
        [S
                [NP$_2^1\downarrow$]
                [S
                        [NP
                                [PRO]]
                        [VP
                                [NP$_2^1$
                                        [e]]
                                [NP$_2^2$
                                        [e]]
                                [V$_2$
                                        [zu überf\"uhren]]]]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}

\end{forest}
```

I know of `s` and `s sep`, but I would prefer a style specification that does this for all TAG trees and I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please, consider [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Answer (score 7):

May be `fit=rectangle` (page 29) is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{standalone}   

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
tag/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top}},
% a style that creates an arrow pointing to the substitution node from a tree top node encoded as daughter 
substitution/.style={edge={<-,dashed},l+=\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$\downarrow$,
          [NP, substitution
            [John]]]
        [VP
                [V
                        [laughs]]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{2em}
\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$_2^2\downarrow$]
        [S, fit=rectangle
                [NP$_2^1\downarrow$]
                [S, fit=rectangle,
                        [NP
                                [PRO]]
                        [VP
                                [NP$_2^1$
                                        [e]]
                                [NP$_2^2$
                                        [e]]
                                [V$_2$
                                        [zu überf\"uhren]]]]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I took the fit=band option, although I do not see a difference for the examples at hand. I added the fit-declaration to the style declaration so that it applies to all nodes automatically. Thanks a lot! This package is a monster! But I am getting closer to understanding something. =:-)

Comment: @StefanMüller Similarly here. This answer seems to have solved your problem and, if it has, you should consider accepting it.